# Generic based WebService

Tags: web-services, generics, esb

I would like to do an ESB solution, where I want to use a generic based webservice.
I can do the definition, generate all needed classes, the service exists, but the wsdl deficient. Missing the "generic part", that part what defined by generic type.

The ancestor:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = { "header", "body" })
public abstract class WSRequest<T> {

protected RequestHeader header;
protected T body;

public RequestHeader getHeader()
{
    return header;
}

public void setHeader(RequestHeader header)
{
    this.header = header;
}

public T getBody()
{
    return body;
}

public void setBody(T body)
{
    this.body = body;
}
```

}

And the descendant:

```
public class PartnerRequest extends WSRequest<PartnerData>
{

}
```

The service work correctly, but the generated wsdl doesn't contain the PartnerData structure. 
I'm new in WS part, so that is the real possibility it is impossible. 
Please help me to solve the problem (or reject this idea)

Thx!
Feri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that, the base XSD was too complex. (I generated it by an XML, and th generator program made very elegant xsd, what was unusable! :-( )
Too complex mean:

```
....
<xs:element ref="ugyfelKod"/>
...
<xs:element name="ugyfelKod" type="xs:NCName"/>
...
```